# Could not open Cooling pad fan

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

I am trying to open a brushless DC fan of computer [Belkin](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F5L001) cooling pad. I have accessed the fan from the cooling pad. I don't see any screws to deattach the fan from the motor. Please see the images below,

[image]

[image]

Comment: so... what do you wish to do?

Comment: I wish to lubricate the shaft it is making horrible noise.

Comment: Looks like a standard fan, those are really cheap - you can consider replacing it with a new one.

Comment: they really aren't made to be taken apart and repaired... the assembly process is pretty much a one-way process.  Taking it apart will more than likely result in damaging it, as opposed to enabling you to repair it.  For example, with that fan, you may have to remove the fan blade from the motor axle, but in attempting to do so, you will most likely damage the axle assembly, making it wobble or drop when in operation.  @gronostaj is very correct.  Try to replace the fan.

Comment: They aren't made to be taken apart, but if you study carefully you can probably find a seam to work at with a pocket knife.  May be glued or may just be attached with "snap" action.  Probably the side in the second shot -- you'd pry off that cap in the middle.  Under the cap you'll find the end of the (fixed) shaft, probably with the armature held on via a spring clip of some sort.  But be advised that even if you do manage to lube it, likely the bushings are shot and the lube won't last very long.  (Did my first computer fan surgery in 1970.)

Answer (score 0):

if you can see at the bottom of the motor , you'll see the rotor shaft.
around that shaft there's a ring maybe of plastic , rubber or a metal .
By removing that ring you can remove the whole fan from the stator part of motor.
This is because of a sleeve ring cut at rotor's shaft towards inside to lock it with the stator .